# Borel functions and continuous functions

Tags: measure-theory, functions, continuity, approximation

Suppose we have a set $A\subset\mathbb {R}$ and let $f\in\mathcal{B}(A)$ and $g\in\mathcal{B}_b(A)$ (Borel function on $A$ and bounded Borel function on $A$, resp.) Is it possible to approximate $f$ and/or $g$ by continuous functions on $A$ in a certain sense (pointwise, uniform, etc.)? So yes, how to prove that, or what are the references? So no, what is a counterexample?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: The uniform limit of continuous functions is continuous. Any pointwise limit of continuous functions is Borel, but not *vice versa*. In fact, you can stratify the class of Borel functions into [$\omega_1=\aleph_1$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aleph_number) many sub-classes, by starting with the continuous functions, continuing with Baire one functions (the pointwise limits of sequences of continuous functions), then with Baire two functions (pointwise limits of Baire one functions), etc.